# XGBoost - Output boosting rounds

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, xgboost

I'm using Scikit-Learn API, `XGBRegressor`. I'm trying to make my model as verbose as possible. These are the parameters of the model. This is running on Kaggle kernels. `df_train` and `df_target` are pandas dataframes.

```
model = xgb.XGBRegressor(
    n_estimators=2**8,
    max_depth=5,
    learning_rate=0.04,
    subsample=0.9,
    colsample_bytree=0.9,    
    objective='reg:squarederror',
    booster='gbtree',
    importance_type='weight',
    tree_method='gpu_hist',
    silent=False,    
    random_state=SEED
)
```

and this is the parameters of `fit()`. I have to see training rmse between boosting rounds like in the LightGBM. Does XGBoost have that functionality?

```
model.fit(df_train, df_target, eval_metric='rmse', eval_set=[(df_train, df_target)], verbose=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes It has. You just have to set the eval_set parameterYes It has. You just have to set the eval_set parameter:

XGB.fit(X_train,y_train, eval_set = [(X_test, y_test)], verbose = True)

Comment: I didn't understand the question. The output that you want to see is something like that?
Output?
[11] validation_0-rmse:2.67241 validation_1-rmse:2.68524
[12] validation_0-rmse:2.4146 validation_1-rmse:2.42833
[13] validation_0-rmse:2.18278 validation_1-rmse:2.19782
[14] validation_0-rmse:1.97601 validation_1-rmse:1.99251
[15] validation_0-rmse:1.7892 validation_1-rmse:1.80586

Comment: Yes that's what I wanted to see, but my code is same as yours

Comment: Try setting your eval_set to a different dataset. Train setting it as the dataset for testing. Ex: model.fit(df_train, df_target, eval_metric='rmse', eval_set=[(X_test, y_test)], verbose=True)